# A statement lambda stating not all code paths return value

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

```
delegate int test9(int c,int l);

//Main method
test9 de = (int a, int b) =>  b += 2;     //no error
test9 xr = (int a, int b) => { b += 2; }; //error
```

So I have the delegate `test9` which return an int and takes to int parameters.
in case of `de` instance of the `test9`, the expression returns the result of `b+=2` but when I use statement lambda, the compiler says that not all code paths return value.
I mean is there a code that the compiler generates in case of expressions like `return the result of the expression`? So basically it writes a `return` before the statement.
If that is not case, could you please tell me what exactly happens under the hood in detail?

Comment: This is what the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties#computed-properties) call an _expression-bodied member_ - _Expression-bodied members use the lambda expression syntax to define methods that contain a single expression._. Adding curly brackets stops this from being a single expression, hence the need for `return`.

Comment: To add on to what @stuartd says, make the lambda be `(int a, int b) => { b += 2;  return b; };` and you should be good to go.

Comment: For the second one, `{ return b += 2; }` would be the *exact* equivalent to the first one.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you, I am just trying to understand if the compiler sort of adds a _return_ before the `b+=2` when I do not use brackets.

Comment: Yes it does. When you use `(int a, int b) => b += 2;` the lambda expression to the right of the `=>` is evaluated as the value returned when the lambda is run. When you put in braces, think of it as behaving just like a function body - i.e. needing a return statement